# Using on function on span tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to toggle between span and input text field using on function but I need some help in finding out what I am doing wrong.

I have created a fiddle for it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RUwtt/392/)

**UI**

```
<div>
<span >My value here!</span>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var focusInName = '';
var focusOutName = '';
$(function () {
    $("document").on("click",".span", function () {
        var input = $('<input />', {'type': 'text', 'name': 'aname', 'value': $(this).html()});
        $(this).parent().append(input);
        $(this).remove();
        input.focus();
        focusInName = $(this).html();
        alert(focusInName);
    });

    $('document').on('blur',".input", function () {
        $(this).parent().append($('<span />').html($(this).val()));
        $(this).remove();
         focusOutName = $(this).val();
        alert(focusOutName);
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you sure you need this construct, rather than a simple [`contenteditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable)? Also: wow, a fiddle with 392 revisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use simple [`contenteditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_Editable)

```
 <span contentEditable="true">My value here!</span>
```

---

You need to use jQuery 1.7+ as [`$.fn.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) as it was added in 1.7

*HTML*, Initially add the required class i.e. `span` to your element

```
<span class='span'>My value here!</span>
```

*Code*:

```
var focusInName = '';
var focusOutName = '';
$(function () {
    $(document).on("click", ".span", function () {
        focusInName = $(this).html();
        var input = $('<input />', {
            'type': 'text',
                'name': 'aname',
                'value': $(this).html(),
                'class': 'input' //Add the CSS class while creating element
        });
        input.focus();
        $(this).parent().append(input);
        $(this).remove(); //Always remove at the end
        alert(focusInName);
    });

    $(document).on('blur', ".input", function () {
        focusOutName = $(this).val();
        var span = $(
            '<span />', {
            'class': 'span', //Add the CSS class while creating element
            'html': $(this).val()
        });

        $(this).parent().append(span);
        $(this).remove();  //Always remove at the end      
        alert(focusOutName);
    });
});
```

The modified [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/c4dac5tj/)

Comment: thank you sir. I have modified your code a little. Moved the input.focus() after $(this).remove()..here;s the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/c4dac5tj/1/

Answer (score 2):

You should change the version of the jquery to 1.9
And change the class to html element like this:

```
 $(document).on("click","span", function () {
//codes
}
```

And same for the input field:

```
$(document).on('blur',"input", function () {
//codes    
 }
```

**Edit**

If you want to set the classes to the html elements you can do as follows:

```
var focusInName = '';
var focusOutName = '';
$(function () {
    $(document).on("click",".sp", function () {
        var input = $('<input class="box" />', {'type': 'text', 'name': 'aname','value': $(this).html()});
        $(this).parent().append(input);
        $(this).remove();
        input.focus();
        focusInName = $(this).html();
        alert(focusInName);
    });

    $(document).on('blur',".box", function () {
        $(this).parent().append($('<span class="sp" />').html($(this).val()));
        $(this).remove();
         focusOutName = $(this).val();
        alert(focusOutName);
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RUwtt/396/)

Comment: Note that this works on all the spans on the entire page, which may not be what the OP wanted.

Comment: @AkashRajbanshi, thanks for your reply. I ran you fiddle and noticed that if I am clicking on the text, the span changes to input, but the input does not retain the text. Moreover, if I empty the input field and click anywhere outside the input field, I can no longer toggle. Do you have a solution for these two scenarios?